# MissingConstraints lint error when using Flow

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, lint, android-lint

I'm using the recently released constraint layout version 2.0 and they have added a new feature called `Flow` which basically replaces what linear layout used to do ( with more customization ). But the android lint is blocking my CI from building because it thinks the views are missing constraint. Suppressing this lint error for each of these views seems a plan B so am asking if there is a way to update lint independently from other components of the Gradle.

Currently running:

- Gradle = 6.1.1
- AndroidGradlePlugin = 4.0.1
- Kotlin = 1.4

Comment: You can add `tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"` to the _ConstraintLayout_ to suppress the warning for all of its children. This will effect elements of _Flow_ as well as all others, so it's not a perfect solution. Lint really needs to be updated to suppress this warning for members of _Flow_ if constraints are not truly needed.

Comment: Yes, I ended up doing this. You can also define `lint.xml` file at the root of the project to ignore certain paths. Let's wait until they update lint then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They just fixed it in Android Studio 4.1 RC3 https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/79995034

Comment: When you use gradle `lint` command (`gradlew :app:lint`) then even Android Gradle Plugin `4.2.0-beta04` doesn't work. I add this comment also in that issue

Comment: It's not fixed in Android Studio 4.1.2. [This](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/79995034#comment3) comment in the IssueTracker thread implies it's fixed for Android Studio 4.2. I'll wait for the stable release of Android Studio 4.2 before trying it again and I'll keep my `tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"` declarations in place for now.

Answer (score 7):

Make sure that you don't have spaces between ids values in `app:constraint_referenced_ids` attribute so if you have e.g. this:

```
app:constraint_referenced_ids="view_1, view_2, view_3"
```

you should rewrite it to:

```
app:constraint_referenced_ids="view_1,view_2,view_3"
```

also you can suppress such warning for a particular view by setting `tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"` to it or for all the views by setting that attribute for the parent `ConstraintLayout` but it isn't recommend.

Comment: This is an old question. It has already been fixed and this wasn't the issue I was having.

Comment: no problem, hope my answer will help someone who faced with the same issue